# Getting Error: The method run() of type Gamepanel must override or implement a supertype method?

Tags: java

I am getting the error

> Error: The method run() of type Gamepanel must override or implement a supertype method.

But I have the `@Override` right on top the run method.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Gamepanel extends JPanel {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static final int WIDTH = 500, HEIGHT = 500; 

  public Gamepanel(){ 
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
  }

  public void start(){ 
  }

  public void stop(){
  }

  public void trick(){
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
    for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH/10; i++){
     g.drawLine(i * 10, 0, i *10, HEIGHT); 
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT/10; i++){
     g.drawLine(0, i * 10, HEIGHT, i * 10); 
    } 
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
  } 
}
```

Comment: Gamepanel class doesn't extend anything so no methods can override anything except those of Object.

Comment: Another possibility is that you meant to implement Runnable and didn't add that to the class definition line.

Answer (score 0):

The class JPanel does not have a method named run() and hence Overriding the same is not possible.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html shows you the methods under JPanel.

In other words, run() is an implementation of your class and not any of the parent type.